# Converting the one form of JSON Array Data to another?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to software Field. i have a json array of objects like

```
var treeObj = [
      {
        "name": "sriram",
        "refernce_id": "SAN001",
        "sponer_id": "SAN000"
      },
      {
        "name": "neeraja",
        "refernce_id": "SAN002",
        "sponer_id": "SAN001"
      },
      {
        "name": "upender",
        "refernce_id": "SAN003",
        "sponer_id": "SAN001"
      },
      {
        "name": "manoj",
        "refernce_id": "SAN004",
        "sponer_id": "SAN002"
      },
      {
        "name": "shirisha",
        "refernce_id": "SAN005",
        "sponer_id": "SAN002"
      },
      {
        "name": "ragu",
        "refernce_id": "SAN006",
        "sponer_id": "SAN003"
      },
      {
        "name": "santhu",
        "refernce_id": "SAN007",
        "sponer_id": "SAN003"
      }
    ];
```

Here i will pass the above object to a function. in that function i need to compare reference id with sponer_id in every object and if they are equal we need to push them into an Array which we call as child object just like below and again we need to check in the child Array that the reference id in is present in sponer_id of above object if it is present again we need to push them to child array into object which contains the reference_id. the final array Object looks like.

```
[
  {
    "name": "sriram",
    "parent": null,
    "children": [
      {
        "name": "neeraja",
        "parent": "sriram",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "manoj",
            "parent": "neeraja"
          },
          {
            "name": "shirisha",
            "parent": "neeraja"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "upender",
        "parent": "sriram",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "ragu",
            "parent": "neeraja"
          },
          {
            "name": "santhu",
            "parent": "neeraja"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Here sriram's reference id of treeObj is present as sponer id in neeraja and upender object. so neeraja and upender becomes child to sriram. and neeraja's reference_id is present as sponer_id in manoj and shirisha objects of treeObj. simultaneously the child can many more child objects and we need to format the object dynamically.

The function which i wrote looks like

```
var mainArr = [], subArrs = [], subObj={}, subIds = [], find = "SAN001";
    formatData(treeObj);
    function formatData(treeObj){debugger;
        var arr = [];
        for(var x=0; x<= treeObj.length-1; x++){debugger;
            var sampData = treeObj[x];
            if(find == sampData.sponer_id){
                arr.push(sampData.refernce_id);
                subArrs.push(sampData);
            }
        }
        subIds.push(arr);
        console.log(subIds);
        console.log(subArrs);
        formatData(subArrs);
    }
```

please guide me where i went wrong. thanks in advance.

Comment: `Java` is not `JavaScript`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//1. find all items the have no parent and push them on a stack like so:

let stack = treeObj.reduce((list, item) => {
  if (<ids match>) list.push(item);
  return item;
}, []),

let result = [].concat(stack);

//2. while loop the stack:

while (stack.length > 0) {
  let item = stack.shift();

  item.children = treeObj.reduce((list, child) => {
    if (<ids match>) {
      list.push(child);
    }
    return list;
  }, []).map(child => {
      child.parent = item;
      stack.unshift(item);
      return child;
  });
}

return result;
```

**UPDATE**

So in »good old JS« and with some improvements:

```
var stack = treeObj.filter(function (item) { 
  return item.<parent_id> === item.<child_id> });

var result = [].concat(stack);

while (stack.length > 0) {
  var item = stack.shift();

  item.children = treeObj.filter(function (child) {
    return item.<id> === child.<parent_id>;
  });

  item.children.forEach(function (child) { stack.unshift(child) });
}
```

Basically:

1. find the root(s) and save them on the stack
2. `while.length > 0`

   1. `shift()` the first item from the stack
   2. find all children of that item and `unshift` them on the stack
3. Done

Adding a parent property to the items, or removing unneeded one, can be done in the loop. The whole thing can also be done using recursion, but I once ran in the »too much recursion error« by doing such stuff, so I prefer an iterative approach. And of course, instead of `.reduce`, `.filter` and `.forEach`, you can use regular loops, but I prefer a functional style. All in all, no matter how you do it, it is not that difficult, just find the elements to start with and then repeat with all of their children and so on. Withing the `while` loop all children are found, or, the whole subtree with that element as root.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the reply, philip. but i'm getting the error as 
Uncaught SyntaxError: let is disallowed as a lexically bound name

Comment: This is ES6, the new version of JS.

Comment: Thank you so much philip... :) your logic worked like charm.

Answer (score 0):

You're basically trying to convert an array to a n-ary tree.

Entering your original tree function into formatData gives you an array (arr) with the referenceIDs of all objects having SAN001 as parent and another array (subArrs) with all children of with sponerId SAN001.

You then store the arr in subIds, log subIds and subArr and proceed to call format data on subArrs recursively. Then you check on subArr which objects have "SAN001 as predecessor" (which should be all objects at that time) and push that object in subArr. If im not getting it wrong this leads to an infinite loop.

Starting points for improvements:
you're "find" variable does not change, it's hardwired to "SAN001" - this would maybe be okay for your first trip when you're 100% sure that the root object has always this referenceID. But in the second trip, you want to check which objects depend on a second level element, so you need to set find to an corresponding referenceId.

Your subArrs contains all objects depending on SAN001. But in the second and following trips, you don't want to get childrens of SAN001 but child of objects in the subArr. So you need to travers old objects finding children of objects in subArr instead of traversing subArr seeking children of SAN001.

Hope that clear's it up a little bit.

A hint for further research: You're basically trying to "convert an array into a n-ary tree" with javascript.